# hiding some posts from homepage using label blogger

Tags: blogger

I used code to hide certain things from the homepage(they will be available on other pages) but now the posts i hide go away but there is some stuff left from that post such as the date etc.

code:

```
  <div class='post-outer'>

          <!--<b:include data='post' name='post'/>-->
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == &quot;true&quot;'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.name != &quot;other pagles&quot;'>
                <b:include data='post' name='post' />
            </b:if>
        </b:if>
    </b:loop>
<b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post' />
</b:if>-->
<!--end-->
```

what it looks like:

[image: pic of blog]

Comment: Very impressed so far...

Comment: Try to send blog widget code at least because post date comes before your code.